# rust drop call sequence after implmenting drop trait

Tags: rust

I am new to rust. My simple code

```
struct Foo<'a>{
    data : & 'a String,
}
fn test_foo(){
   let s1:String = String::from("A"); 
   let mut foo:Foo = Foo { data: & s1 };
   let s2:String = String::from("B");
   foo.data = & s2;  
}
```

My query : If I implement Drop trait for Foo struct

```
foo.data = & s2;
```

starts giving compilation error : `s2` does not live long enough. The error makes sense to me. But, why am I not getting the same error if I don't implement Drop trait for Foo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are non-lexical lifetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251487/what-are-non-lexical-lifetimes)

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74106698/does-the-drop-trait-in-rust-modify-scoping-rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rust, local variables (from the same scope) are dropped in reverse order of the order they're defined.

```
fn test_foo(){
   let s1:String = String::from("A"); 
   let mut foo:Foo = Foo { data: & s1 };
   let s2:String = String::from("B");
   foo.data = & s2;  
}
```

We declare three local variables here: `s1`, `foo`, and `s2`, in that order. Rust would like to drop them in reverse order: `s2` first, then `foo`, then `s1`. However, there's a problem with the lifetimes. Once we drop `s2`, then `foo.data` is *uninitialized*, i.e. it points to garbage memory.

Now, why does this work without `Drop`? Rust has a concept called [partial moves](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/move/partial_move.html). If you have a structure that has multiple fields, Rust will allow you to move out of some fields without invalidating the whole struct. In principle, if I have a

```
struct Person {
  name: String,
  age: i32,
  occupation: String,
}
```

and I do `let name = my_person.name;` (where `my_person: Person`), then I've moved a value out of a `Person`. Thus, `my_person.name` is invalid, and in the absence of partial moves, Rust should consider `my_person` completely invalid. However, we know that `my_person.age` and `my_person.occupation` are still valid, so Rust will let `age` and `occupation` remain in place. It remembers that `name` is moved (and hence garbage that should not be dropped), while `age` and `occupation` are still valid.

In your example, the same thing is happening. Rust wants to drop `s2`, but `Foo` still holds a reference to it. Rust considers that fine: We'll drop `s2` and simply say that `Foo` has been *partially moved*: Its `data` field is no longer valid. Then when we go to drop `foo` next, we don't need to drop the reference, merely the outermost `Foo` layer itself.

Without a `Drop` instance, this is fine, and Rust will allow it. However, if `impl<'a> Drop for Foo<'a>` is in scope, then partial moves are *completely disabled* for `Foo`. Rust sees that you're implementing some custom `Drop` behavior, and now it won't allow a partially-initialized object to exist, since we would have to drop a partially-initialized object, and Rust can't predict what your custom `Drop` code is going to do or what assumptions it's going to make.

So with a `Drop` implementation, Rust still wants to drop `s2` first, but it can't partially move the reference out of `foo`, since that would leave `foo` in a partially-initialized state, which isn't allowed.